# Set upper volume limit for pavucontrol

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, volume-control, pavucontrol

I'm using **Lubuntu Xenial** with `pulseaudio` and the issue which I'm facing is that the upper volume limit isn't set for `pavucontrol` which leads to **unnecessary** amplification which in turn results in bad audio quality, when I increase the volume increment command `pactl set-sink-volume 0 +5%`.
If possible I'd like to limit the max volume to 100% just like it is in `alsamixer`.

Comment: Do you mean disabling over-amplification? `gsettings set com.ubuntu.sound allow-amplified-volume false`?

Comment: Yes, I meant over-amplification. I'm currently away from my PC so I'll update here when I get the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had the same question and went nuts trying to find a solution.

I downloaded pavucontrol's source code, and there is no config file fix.

Apparently this is the recommended value because that's what [PA_VOLUME_UI_MAX is set to](https://freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/doxygen/volume_8h.html#a353b44010677b005abd390af732eb86e). Changing all instances of PA_VOLUME_UI_MAX for PA_VOLUME_NORM and rebuilding is the only solution I can see.

It is "by design". Honestly I'm at a loss of words because over amplification can permanently damage the speakers; that this is the recommended default doesn't speak very well about the audio engineering knowledge of the programmers. If someone wants to go overdrive, fine; but it shouldn't be the default.

Comment: Your thoughts resonate well with mine! I too got frustrated and had to switch to `alsa` for this. I perhaps also switched to `amixer` to fix this for `pulseaudio`.